# How many episodes did the second anime season of Nanatsu no Taizai have?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Supposedly Nanatsu no Taizai is currently running the 4th season. There is a season aired in 2014 which had 24 episodes, there is another season aired in 2018 which had 24 episodes, 4th season is currently running, and I only can find listed 4 episodes made in 2016. Is that the second season or those are OVAs?

How many episodes did the second anime season of Nanatsu no Taizai have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 2019, officially in Japan, **there are 4 series, but only 3 seasons**:

1. *Nanatsu no Taizai* (2014): 1st season, 24 episodes
2. *Nanatsu no Taizai: Seisen no Shirushi* (2016): TV Special, 4 episodes, in which the last episode revealed the announcement for *the 2nd season* (see also [Why is Nanatsu no Taizai : Seisen no Shirushi only 4 episodes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36476))
3. *Nanatsu no Taizai: Imashime no Fukkatsu* (2018): 2nd season, 24 episodes
4. *Nanatsu no Taizai: Kamigami no Gekirin* (2019): 3rd season, ? episodes

However, localization (and sometimes fans' opinion) make season count inconsistent or confusing, as Netflix considers each series as its own session:

1. *The Seven Deadly Sins* (2014): Season 1
2. *The Seven Deadly Sins: Signs of Holy War* (2016): Season 2
3. *The Seven Deadly Sins: Revival of The Commandments* (2018): Season 3
4. *The Seven Deadly Sins: Wrath of the Gods* (2019): Season 4